# Where can I post a Winter Bash test question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, winter-bash

I want to post a test question to either:

- Gain a Winter Bash hat, or
- Test a theory about the criteria for awarding a secret hat.

Where can I post such a test question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Is there a sandbox to post test questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/is-there-a-sandbox-to-post-test-questions) you can use the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Unfortunately the Formatting Sandbox only allows new *answers* to be posted not *questions*.

However, one of the up-voted answers to [Is there a sandbox to post test questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/is-there-a-sandbox-to-post-test-questions) suggests that test questions are allowed as long as they are deleted as soon as possible.